# Как запустить bat через python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Надо запустить bat файл через python3
Как это сделать

```
import time
while True:
    ... Вот тут нужно запустить bat...
    time.sleep(900)
    break
```

Comment: `import os` + `os.system(<путь к bat>)` . Либо, использовать модуль `subprocess`, если нужен контроль на запускаемой программой

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import os
while True:
    os.system('./name.bat') #Вообще system это функция, для ввода чего-либо в терминал
    time.sleep(900)
    break
```